# I want to add two numbers of different iterations

Tags: python, loops, addition

The function here takes 2 integers k and l and gives the number k in base l. Now the loop prints all the numbers in base 2 from 0 to 100.
What I want to do is that if the last digit of 2 different iterations is same, then add the numbers
Code:

```
def base(k,l):
    result=''
    while k!=0:
        remainder = k%l
        k=k//l
        result= str(remainder)+ result  
    return result
t=10
for i in range(100):
    print('0'+base(i,2).zfill(t))
```

I cannot append them in a list or array as my iterations are very large and will consume too much memory. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: `variable1 = '0'+base(i,2).zfill(t)` and `if variable1[-2] != variable2[-2] and variable1[-1] != variable2[-1]`

Comment: @furas can you post the answer and explain what you did?

Comment: i don't see `a` and `b` in your code. And I don't understand if you want to compare number from any iteration or only iterations one after another.

Comment: @furas Sorry, my bad. Edited

Comment: I still don't know if you want to compare only iterations one after another or any two iterations. For any two iterations you will have to keep on list because you never know when will be next number with the same digits.

Comment: @furas that is the issue. I can't keep it in a list because number of my iterations are very large

Comment: then you will have to save in file and somehow later read from file and compare - and this will use more time then using in memory.

Comment: It isn't exactly clear, are you saying if you have number `1235` and `6785` since `5` is the same in both then add them?

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn Yes

Comment: Do you want to accumulate all of the values with the same last digit? To follow on from my last comment, if you also got a `8885` would you then want `1235+6785+8885`? Do you need to retain the original values?

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn No, I want to add only 2 of them. So if numbers are 1235,6785, 8885, add 1235 and 6785, 6785 and 8885, 1235 and 8885

Comment: Is the use case actually a sequential iteration as in the code? Or are you iterating through a somewhat random sequence of numbers? if it is sequential, then it wouldn't be too bad to break this problem into the groups of numbers that will have the same last digit.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn It is sequential iteration. But if I break it into groups, then I would have to store there somewhere and I want to avoid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is to just store the iteration in a `dict` based on the last digit. This would allow you to then recover it later. Since there will be a limited number of digits, this shouldn't consume much memory and we're only storing the iteration value to use later.

```
d = {}
for i in range(100):
    val = '0'+base(i,2).zfill(t)
    if val[-1] in d:
       val2 = d[val[-1]] + i
       #do whatever with this value?
    else: #We haven't had an iteration with the same last digit
       d[val[-1]] = i #store i for later
```

Based on what I think you want to do. I think this next code will solve it.

```
maxRange = 100
baseNum = 2
t=10
for i in range(maxRange):
    val = '0'+base(i,baseNum).zfill(t)
    startVal = int(val[-1]) #Base the startVal on the last digit
    for val2 in range(startVal, i, baseNum): #start at startVal, go to current num and increment by what our base is.
        print(f'{i}+{val2}=')
        print('0'+base(i+val2, baseNum).zfill(t))
```

Example Output:

```
2+0=
00000000010
3+1=
00000000100
4+0=
00000000100
4+2=
...
99+89=
00010111100
99+91=
00010111110
99+93=
00011000000
99+95=
00011000010
99+97=
00011000100
```

Comment: I don't think this would work as `val2` is not generated from base function from your code

Comment: So this would use the base to generate the least significant digit and store the base 10 integer in that key. so for example decimal `10` == `0000001010` in base 2 gets stored in `d['0']` then if you have value decimal `12` == `0000001100` base 2 it uses the lsb of '0' to retrieve `10` and add `12` to that.